# How can I wire Unity to use a factory method during resolution?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am learning the ropes of Unity, and I have trouble setting it up the way I want.

I have set up a MVCE, to illustrate it:

A `Customer` has a name.

```
 public interface ICustomer
    {
        string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Customer : ICustomer
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Customer(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

In order to build the `Customer`, a Factory has been created:

```
public interface ICustomerFactory
{
    ICustomer Create(string name);
}

public class CustomerFactory
    :ICustomerFactory
{
    public ICustomer Create(string name)
    {
        return new Customer(name);
    }
}
```

The main program is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string customerName = "foo";

    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<ICustomerFactory, CustomerFactory>();

    container.Resolve<ICustomer> //I would like this to return a customer named "foo".
}
```

The way I would like it to work:

- When Unity tries to resolve `ICustomer`, it uses the factory associated with it, ICustomerFactory -> **This is where I struggle.**
- `ICustomerFactory` is then resolved to its concrete implementation, `CustomerFactory`, and `Create(customerName)` is called.

Without Unity, it would be something like:

```
ICustomerFactory factory = new CustomerFactory();
ICustomer customer = factory.Create(customerName);
```

I have been looking at the Unity documentation, but it is very hard to understand, and I have trouble making progress.

Comment: What's the use of hiding `Customer` behind an `ICustomer` interface? DI is for building object graphs of _components_, not _entities_. Unity should resolve your `CustomerFactory`, but _never_ your `Customer`. This is something your application should create itself.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the factory and create your customer.

```
var factory = container.Resolve<ICustomer>();
var customer = factory.Create(customerName);
```

Dependency injection is all about *not new'ing* stuff...

Two additional comments:

- if you don't absolutely need to, avoid using the container directly. Instead of injecting the container and calling resolve to get the factory, better have the factory injected in the first place.
- I personally like to use interfaces unless I'm 100% sure I won't need them. They come at virtually no cost but make testing and extending so much easier. The only thing that won't be interfaced will be a DTO, most likely.